# All possible Angram String combinations in java

Tags: java, string, anagram

I've got to make all possible anagram string combinations with java. Checking whether two strings are anagram or not is not my problem.. But when it comes to generating the whole set of possible anagram string combinations, I can't manage to find out a way.

For example : 
Input  : "Wolf"
Output : 
1. wolf
2. wofl
3. wlof
4. wflo
5. wlfo
6. wfol
5. owlf
6. olfw
.
.
.
And so on.

Comment: Have you tried any code? if yes please post it and we can help

Comment: Please post your code, so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 4):

Check this one:

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           String input = "Wolf";
            permutation(input, "");
        }    
        private static void permutation(String input, String sofar) {
            if (input.equals("")) {
                System.out.printf("%s,", sofar);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++) {
                char c = input.charAt(i);
                if (input.indexOf(c, i + 1) != -1)
                continue;
                permutation(input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i + 1), sofar+c);
            }
        }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wolf,Wofl,Wlof,Wlfo,Wfol,Wflo,oWlf,oWfl,olWf,olfW,ofWl,oflW,lWof,lWfo,loWf,lofW,lfWo,lfoW,fWol,fWlo,foWl,folW,flWo,floW
```